# Is there a way to concatenate a vector string based on a numeric vector?

Tags: r

I am trying to create levels of elements that can be paired or independent variables. If paired, I am trying to group them using a numeric vector as a map. I wonder if there is a method for that? Does anyone have a clue?

```
nVector = c(1,2,2)
sVector = c("apple", "strawberry", "blueberry")
```

Maybe the equivalent output of doing:

```
c("apple", paste("strawberry", "blueberry"))
[1] "apple"                "strawberry blueberry"
```

I am also open to other thoughts about it.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 4):

You can try the code below with `tapply`

```
> tapply(sVector, nVector, paste0, collapse = " ")
                     1                      2
               "apple" "strawberry blueberry"
```

Answer (score 4):

The `tapply` answer is what I’d call the “canonical” solution to this but personally I like using `split` to show the intermediate step explicitly:

```
groups = split(sVector, nVector)
vapply(groups, paste, character(1L), collapse = ' ')
```

Comment: I really like this method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Other ways are using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(sVector, list(nVector), paste, collapse = " ")[,2]
#[1] "apple"                "strawberry blueberry"
```

`by`:

```
c(by(sVector, nVector, FUN=paste, collapse = " "))
#                     1                      2 
#               "apple" "strawberry blueberry"
```

`split` with `sapply`:

```
sapply(split(sVector, nVector), paste, collapse = " ")
#                     1                      2 
#               "apple" "strawberry blueberry"
```